# fetch api using acces by token (send token as parameter) on react-native

Tags: api, react-native, networking

**I've this link :**

```
https://link.com/link/  (API)
my token to acces web api is : xxxx
and parameter are  idUser = 1, idCommande = 1
Methode : POST
```

how i can get data from api using this token xxxx ??

Answer (score 0):

You can user json.stringify method to pass tokens.

```
fetch('YOUR_URL', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    idUser : 1,
    idCommande : 1,
  })
})
```

Comment: but what about token !